# Eclipse is telling me resource already exists, while it doesn't

Tags: android, eclipse, android-resources

I have a problem with a weird bug in Eclipse. While editing some button's ID, for some reason Eclipse closed without giving any warning. So I restarted Eclipse, beeing annoyed since I didn't save my edits and everything was back to my last save. So I started renaming the buttons again, but now Eclipse tells me the resource ID already exists, but it doesn't. So I tried cleaning the project, but the problem remains. R.Java keeps those ID's even if they are removed from my project. So I checked my workspace files using Notepad++, but those ID's are not there any more. So anyone who has a clue why those ID's keep popping up in R.Java while there are not present in my project viewer or even the files itself?

Comment: have you tried to delete the `R.java` file?

Comment: just clean and rebuild your project

Answer (score 1):

Generally when one encounter ID-related problems the no brainer fix is to simply *clean project*. Also clean any included project libraries (if applicable) as they too have a generated R.java file with ID's.

Sometimes Eclipse auto-imports `android.R.java` causing problems - this is not a file you want to import but instead you want your own R.java, `your.project.R`.

If this doesn't help, the problem is often that the project does not build properly, therefore for not generating the mentioned `R.java`. Check your resources files, most likely some xml-file is invalid and needs attention before the project builds.

- Clean project
- Make sure android.R is not imported
- Make sure your.project.R is imported
- If R.java isn't generated, look for invalid xml in res folder
- Sometimes restarting Eclipse does help, and you can't clean the project too many times

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! This my own mistake, I changed the ID of buttons, that had the standard names, eg button1, button2 etc. I left the update references box checked, but in the other XML files there where some buttons that still had the standard ID's. So they 2 got updated to the new names. So with my second edit, those where left having the old id.